# Can you increase the spark shell output character limit

Tags: apache-spark

When running code in the spark shell, it is often convenient to have small outputs/a sample printed in the shell directly rather than putting the output in a file.

By default, the shell will truncate such output after a (fairly small) given number of characters. Is there a way that this character limit can be increased? I'm running Spark 1.2

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "output"?

If you want to print *n* lines of an `RDD` use `take()`:

```
myRDD.take(n).foreach(println)
```

According [Spark Programming Guide 1.2.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html), this function "Return an array with the first n elements of the dataset. Note that this is currently not executed in parallel. Instead, the driver program computes all the elements."

Comment: What you did there would be an example of what I mean. Sometimes it will just print the results of an operation. I usually do something like 'take(10)' which may be truncated. This would also happen to individual lines if they were quite long, although this is probably good enough most of the time.